# app appears different on the simulator than in story board

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I just got into iOS development and I'm trying to build a to-do list app. I made the basic layout, but when I run it on the simulator it looks different than from what I see on the storyboard.

Basically, how I did it was that I put a UIView and UITable view in one stack view and pinned it to the 4 edges of the screen. I then set the alignment to "fill" and the distribution to "fill proportionally".
On the storyboard, the UIView is on the top 20-25% of the screen and the rest is the table view. On the simulator, however, it looks like they each take up half of the screen.
[here's an image of the simulator and the storyboard showing the difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJh7i.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the fact that you are depending on the stack view to layout the UIView and UITable for you.  If you take them out of the stack view, you can specify a specific height for the top area (UIView) and pin the bottom of the top area (UIView) to the top of the bottom area (UITableView).

Alternatively, you could keep them in a stack view and change the distribution to "fill" and the Content Hugging Priority of the UITableView to be less than the UIView.  That will make the UIView as big as it needs to be and let the UITableView take up the rest of the space, which sounds like what you want.  This is a good write up of the different distribution possibilities for a stack view:

https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/06/22/uistackview-distribution/

Comment: I did the second option (where u keep it inside the stack view), but I got an error saying that it needs a y position for both the UITableView and the UIView. If I let it fix the error, then I get other constraint errors when I switch to a smaller screen.

Comment: That has nothing to do with what I was talking about.  You need to pin the Stack View to the top/bottom/left/right of the parent view.  You need to have something within the UIView, pinned to the UIView top and bottom, or you need to specify a height or minimum height for the UIView.  It's really hard to give more specifics without knowing what you are trying to do.

Comment: Based on your image, it looks like you want a header.  Well, that header should have a fixed height.  It sounds like you are not specifying a height for the UIView, nor anything within the UIView.